# Problems with Manually Installing an Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Okay, so here's my problem:

On my home computer, I have a Google Chrome Extension installed - WXFZ's \Code. This extension works perfectly, I use it every day for work purposes. However, I guess the developer gave up on it, because it can no longer be found on the Google Extensions download page.

I'm trying to transfer that extension from my home computer to my office computer. I have the extension folder on my work computer and I've tried dragging and dropping it into the extensions page to install it, but I receive an error:

"Could not load extension from 'U:\Downloads\pekinghlicdifnlgafajjohhoiochfdh\2.1_0'.      The 'manifest_version' key must be present and set to 2 (without quotes). See        developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html for details."

I'm not entirely sure what that means, but I've copied the contents of the manifest folder below. I've tried changing some things around in the manifest file, but nothing would work :/

```
{
   "app": {
      "launch": {
         "local_path": "bscode.html"
      }
   },
   "background_page": "storage.html",
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "js/bscode.js", "js/bscode-cs.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
   } ],
   "description": "Simple \\code and \\\\macro engine for common web-forms.",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon_128.png",
      "16": "icon.png",
      "48": "icon_48.png"
   },
   "key":        "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQClVb9xGcyZp3P4Fe+rpjGUqVrvRq8rqQl278gMjFzmxqD65cu7uf/erOBlFWbAc6YK15yvgnsYn+HDYvoSV4shajLAnytek7CI35nia5AnYACJsXW+JrfoT9pEgK9Zd4fE1XFr8bNCzhwKeoupH+gtMdvJ9lqAN4Xj/Tam5+QvzQIDAQAB",
   "name": "wxfz\u2019s \\code",
   "permissions": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "tabs" ],
   "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": 2
}
```

Any advice on this problem, I'd appreciate it. Like I said, the extension still works; I was assuming there has to be a way to get it to work on my other computer :/

***UPDATE***

My apologies, the updated source code is :

```
{
   "app": {
      "launch": {
         "local_path": "bscode.html"
      }
   },
   "background_page": "storage.html",
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "js/bscode.js", "js/bscode-cs.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
   } ],
   "description": "Simple \\code and \\\\macro engine for common web-forms.",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon_128.png",
      "16": "icon.png",
      "48": "icon_48.png"
   },
   "key":"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQClVb9xGcyZp3P4Fe+rpjGUqVrvRq8rqQl278gMjFzmxqD65cu7uf/erOBlFWbAc6YK15yvgnsYn+HDYvoSV4shajLAnytek7CI35nia5AnYACJsXW+JrfoT9pEgK9Zd4fE1XFr8bNCzhwKeoupH+gtMdvJ9lqAN4Xj/Tam5+QvzQIDAQAB",
   "name": "wxfz\u2019s \\code",
   "permissions": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "tabs" ],
   "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "2.1"
   "manifest_version": 2

}
```

In the original post I had:

```
"version": 2
```

I see now that was incorrect, it was supposed to be 2.1, so I changed that back, along with making the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is asking for a `"manifest_version": 2` property in your **[manifest.json](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest.html)**. So, at the very least youneed to:

1. Change `"version": 2` to `"version": "2"` (*version* must be a string value).
2. Add `"manifest_version": 2` (*2* without quotes - it's a number value).
3. Change `"background_page": "storage.html",` to `"background": {"page": "storage.html"},`.

Beware though that some features may break and need refactoring as well (in order to conform with manifest v2).

---

**UPDATE:**

It turned out there were quite a few things that needed to be changed in order for the extension to be compliant with **[Manifest V2](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest.html)** (and functional). The re is no point in posting the code here or list every single modification in detail, so I'll try to summarize and focus on the "nature" of the modification (see further down for a link to the updated source code):

The major source of problems was the fact that the new **[Content Security Policy (CSP)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)** that applies to Google Chrome Extensions does not allow `eval` and inline scripts/event listeners. To circumvent this the following changes were necessary:

1. Declare a CSP in the manifest that allows `eval`
   (`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`).
   Unfortunately(?) there is no way to relax the policy against inline scripts.
2. In the background page (namely `storage.html`, an inline script was used, so I ended up moving the code to an external file (`background.js`) and including the JS scripts like this:

   ```
   "background": {
      "persistent": true,
      "scripts": [
          "js/bscode.js",
          "js/background.js"
      ]
   },
   ```
3. The old `jquery-1.4.4` (which relies on inline scripting) was a no go as well. So I had to replace to the less old `jquery-1.7.2` (I tried using the latest versions of `jquery` and `jquery-ui`, but they didn't play well with the rest of the code, so I rolled back to the oldest version that didn't rely on inline scripting). This change affected both the `content_scripts` declaration and `bscode.html` (where the user-defined macros are defined and edited).
4. Migrating to `jquery-1.7.2` required porting all occurrences of the deprecated `.live()` to the equivalent syntax using `.on()`. (Luckily, this only affected one file: `chrome-ui.js`)
5. `bscode.html` had 2 inline scripts that needed to be moved to an external file (and placed at the right place inside the body, since the code calls `document.write`.
6. `bscode.html` had a lot of inline event listeners, which would not work. Furthermore, elements (which also contain inline event listeners) are inserted dynamicaly into the DOM, so the solution had to take that into account as well.
   I tackled both the problems by using an external JS file that utilizes a **[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)** to listen for node insertions and convert any inline event listeners to "attached" event listeners (by means of `addEventListener()`).

Finally, to make things easier, I set-up `bscode.html` as the `Options Page` for the extension, so you can quickly bring it up from the `chrome://exrensions` page.

<sub>(I hope I didn't leave something out...)</sub>

The refactored (and fully functional as far as I can tell) source code of the extension can be downloaded **[here](https://db.tt/9RvKEDVB)**.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I made the changes that you mentioned and I'm getting a new error - http://screencast.com/t/eT2VEkACgmT

Comment: I wonder how you expect me to guess what the problem is with _Line 24, Column 4_ without providing the source code itself. But challenge accepted anyway :P Did you add a `,` after `"version": "2"` ? If that is not the problem, please post the actual code.

Comment: I've updated the original post including the new source code. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Have you even read my comment above ? I aksed if you have a `,` after `"version": "2.1"`. It turns out you haven't. So, put a comma after `..."2.1"` !

Comment: My apologies, when I initially read that, I was assuming that you were asking, did I put a comma, if so, don't :)

Comment: I went back and added a comma and it did allow me to install it, but I'm receiving an error now on the extensions page: "There were warnings when trying to install this extension:'background_page' requires manifest version of 1 or lower."

Comment: It's also not showing up in my extensions folder, so I'm not sure if it's fully installed or not :/

Comment: Afew things have changed in **[Manifest V2](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest.html)**, so you'll have to update the manifest and possibly some of the HTML files as well. Is it possible to post the code somewhere, so I can take a look ?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you on this. With the holiday season about, things have been hectic. I do appreciate your help with all this; I've posted all the files of the extension over on Github: https://github.com/mjmiller814/pekinghlicdifnlgafajjohhoiochfdh

Comment: It turned out it didn't need much refactoring after all. Please, check my updated answer and report back if you encounter any errors. Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped you solve your problem :)

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested and I was able to install it with no errors. However, the macros I've created are not working :/ I'm adding them from the bscode.html file (as I do at home) and they don't seem to be working :( It may be worth noting that the \enable and \disable commands work, just not my macros

Comment: The built-in macros seem to work, right ? What are `\enable`/`\disable` commands ? How exactly do you open `bscode.html` ?

Comment: The enable and disable macros work. They essentially enable or disable the extension. As far as how I'm creating the macros, I'm opening the bscode.html file from the extensions directory, in the 2.1 folder. There's a "Tutorial" section there that explains it and allows you to test your macros...my macros work just fine there...they just don't work anywhere else. If that makes sense :/

Comment: @mjmiller814: Take a look at my updated answer and let me know if it works for you. Please, don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if you think it is worth it (wait, I believe I have said that already :P).

Comment: Thanks again! Everything works perfectly! I've accepted and upvoted your answer! :)